# ngFor loop is making the webpage slow

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using `*ngFor` in Angular 14. I'm creating Dropdowns in `GenericLayoutComponent` based on the data received from `LaptopComponent`. But it is breaking the browser page:

[image]

Here is the code:

**generic-layout.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let i of data">
  <p-dropdown
    [options]="i"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
    optionLabel="name"
    (onChange)="onChange()"
  ></p-dropdown>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```js
export class GenericLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() product: string;
  @Input() data;

  selectedValue;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onChange() {
    console.log(this.selectedValue);
  }
}
```

Here is the data sent by Laptop component:
**laptop.component.ts**

```
export class LaptopComponent implements OnInit {
  company = [];
  battery_hours = [];
  data = [];

  constructor() {
    this.company = [
      { name: 'Samsung', code: 'SSM' },
      { name: 'Apple', code: 'APL' },
      { name: 'Micromax', code: 'MMx' },
    ];
    this.battery_hours = [
      { name: '10 hours' },
      { name: '25 hours' },
      { name: '32 hours' },
    ];
    this.data = [this.company, this.battery_hours];
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**laptop.component.html**

```
<app-generic-layout [product]="'Laptops'" [data]="data">
</app-generic-layout>
```

I tried to improve the performance of ngFor from here:
[Improving Angular *ngFor Performance Through trackBy](https://betterprogramming.pub/improving-angular-ngfor-performance-through-trackby-ae4cf943b878)

Please check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yrwibx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproducts%2Fgeneric-layout%2Fgeneric-layout.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fproducts%2Flaptop%2Flaptop.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fproducts%2Flaptop%2Flaptop.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fproducts%2Fmobile%2Fmobile.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fproducts%2Fgeneric-layout%2Fgeneric-layout.component.css&file=src%2Fapp%2Fproducts%2Fgeneric-layout%2Fgeneric-layout.component.ts). Please suggest something.

Comment: Hope this helps the OP. Common `selectedValue` model binding for both the array items causes the window to crash. So `selectedValue` instead can be an object which according to an identifiable `key` saves the result. Demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3o3bnv?file=src/app/products/generic-layout/generic-layout.component.html , I made it an object and used array index as key. My approach would have been to start with having `data` not as a list of nested arrays but as a `{key1:list1, key2:list2}` so each **identifiable** key can later be used to save in `selectedValue[key1]`.